# How to change the font style and size for the \lstinputlisting

Tags: fonts, listings

I am trying to insert some piece of code into my document, using the  `\lstinputlisting` command. However the fonts displayed do not look too good. Is it possible to change the font size and style?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the optional argument to provide any `listings` options:

```
\lstinputlisting[basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,language=somelang]{filename}
```

For multiple listings you can set this settings globally (or locally to the current group) using `\lstset{<options>}`. See the `listings` manual for more details.
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings

Answer (score 5):

`\lstinputlisting` obeys to the same options that are set with `\lstset` for the environment form. So something like

```
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,columns=fullflexible}
```

should do.

Comment: What does `columns=fullflexible` do? Could we also set its text width for new line?

Comment: @alper Basically, it sets every letter in a box at its natural width.

Comment: Is it a good idea to reduce box's width? I have a long sentences where it breaks into two due to a single character at the end. I have tried to reduce the space in between using `basewidth=0.5em` since I was not able to use `\!` inside the listing text

Comment: @alper Long sentence in a `lstlisting`?

Comment: yes sir, its actually a code piece like shown here https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/643425/127048 // but even there is empty space at the end of some lines , it is breaked into two. I can ask a new question related to this to not make noise in the comment section

Comment: @alper We need details such as the line width and many others. Better showing the real case in a new question.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/660295/how-can-i-have-most-compact-code-inside-a-lstlisting-frame thanks