# Adding C++ code in Latex

Tags: fonts, listings

So I am adding some C++ code snippets in my document using

```
\lstset {language=C++}
\begin{lstlisting}
for (int i=0; i<iterations;i++)
{
do something
}
\end{lstlisting}
```

My issue is that the font in the code appears different and apparently bigger than the other normal text of the document.Is it supposed to be like this or if not how can I specify a specific size for the font.Also is there a way were I can have a light background for the code something like what I have for the code above?

Comment: Surely some of the existing [tag:listings] questions can provide an answer here?  e.g. [What configuration do you propose for listings.sty to make the output look comfortable?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8230/2693); [How to change the font style and size for the \lstinputlisting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/20721/2693)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is what you could have found out with the manual too and maybe faster than posting your question here ;-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\lstset { %
    language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!5}, % set backgroundcolor
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,% basic font setting
}

\begin{document}
Text before \dots
\begin{lstlisting}
for (int i=0; i<iterations;i++)
{
do something
}
\end{lstlisting}
Text after it \dots
\end{document}
```

If this doesn't answer your question(s) please provide a full working minimal example which illustrates your problem and maybe you can describe the problem more precisely.

Comment: @AnnaVopureta: You can edit the settings for listings individually. You may also take a log at the minted package.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in this [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-typeset-C++-code-in-latex), I'm using the `minted` package. That looks way better.

```
\documentclass{article} 
 
\usepackage{minted} 
 
\begin{document} 
    \begin{minted}{c} 
        #include <stdio.h> 
        int main() { 
            print("Hello, world!"); 
            return 0; 
        } 
    \end{minted} 
\end{document}
```

Below is the output from the same answer.

[image]