# How to upload C code into latex appendix section

Tags: appendices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding C++ code in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21106/adding-c-code-in-latex)

I am trying to upload the code into my latex document.Please let me know how can I do that.My code is as below.

```
\appendix

%My C code goes here
```

Comment: I am supposed to use only appendix.Is it possible only with \appendix tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `listings` package for proper source code formating, or you can just use `\verbatim` environment.

Comment: should be "verbatim", not "verbatium"

Comment: @walkmanyi If you have enough reputation, you can edit the answer and improve it.

Comment: @Marc van Dongen: I tried, but the system refused to accept a trivial edit changing just a single character.

Comment: @walkmanyi It worked for me (the minimal edit).

Comment: @walkmanyi, thank you for correcting my mistake