# lstlisting in a tabular environment

Tags: tables, listings

I am following [Adding C++ code in Latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21106/adding-c-code-in-latex) for adding C++ code to the document.

What I have is a table with the following format:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,final]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset { %
    language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!5}, % set backgroundcolor
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,% basic font setting
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[H]
    \caption{C++ DIC class functions.}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l c c c}
    \toprule[0.2em]

    \textbf{Function in C++} & \textbf{Input} & \textbf{Output} & \textbf{Document corresponding chapter}\\

    \midrule
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{Main setup and API functions. Public functions.}\\
    \begin{lstlisting}
     initialize() 
    \end{lstlisting}
     &sdf & df&f \\
    \bottomrule

    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

My problem is that when I use the lstlisting environment there I only want the "gray" background in the first column, not in the whole line. How can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option would be to keep two separate environments with almost the same settings, except for the background color; inside the table you use the environment without the background color and let `\columncolor` (from the `colortbl` package, loaded through the `table` option for `xcolor`) add the color:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\colorlet{listingscolor}{black!15}

\lstnewenvironment{mylistings}
  {\lstset{language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{listingscolor}, % set backgroundcolor
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,% basic font setting
    }%
  }
  {}

\lstnewenvironment{cpptable}
  {\lstset{language=C++,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,% basic font setting
    }%
  }
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{C++ DIC class functions.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{>{\columncolor{listingscolor}}l c c c}
\toprule[0.2em]
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Function in C++}} & \textbf{Input} & \textbf{Output} & \textbf{Document corresponding chapter}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Main setup and API functions. Public functions.}\\
\begin{cpptable}
 initialize() 
\end{cpptable}
 &sdf & df&f \\
\begin{cpptable}
 another_function() 
\end{cpptable}
 &sdf & df&f \\
\begin{cpptable}
 yet_another_function() 
\end{cpptable}
 &sdf & df&f \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to locally choose an appropriate value for `linewidth`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\lstset{ %
    language=C++,
    backgroundcolor=\color{black!15}, % set backgroundcolor
    basicstyle=\footnotesize,% basic font setting
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\lstset{linewidth=4.5cm}
\caption{C++ DIC class functions.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c c}
\toprule[0.2em]
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Function in C++}} & \textbf{Input} & \textbf{Output} & \textbf{Document corresponding chapter}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Main setup and API functions. Public functions.}\\
\begin{lstlisting}
 initialize() 
\end{lstlisting}
 &sdf & df&f \\
\begin{lstlisting}
 another_function() 
\end{lstlisting}
 &sdf & df&f \\
\begin{lstlisting}
 yet_another_function() 
\end{lstlisting}
 &sdf & df&f \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. It seems that your solutions dont work very well in the longtable enviroment, as the gray bos ovrflows from the bottom. Do you ahve any solution for this?