# Include Doxygen syntax in LaTeX?

Tags: code

I want to write documetation for my current appliaction in LaTeX (about technologies i used and so on) and i wander if i could use section `\mainpage` of Doxygen in him, as a chapter " how to use " , for example.

```
/*! \mainpage My Personal Index Page
 *
 * \section intro_sec Introduction
 *
 * This is the introduction.
 *
 * \section install_sec Installation
 *
 * \subsection step1 Step 1: Opening the box
 *  
 * etc...
 */
```

is this possible? Or all i can do is to write this as effective code?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think, it's possible, but tedious. And it's changing the syntax too much, in my point of view. Especially the label names with `_` will cause trouble

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thank you. If i don't ask for too much, can you give me a minimal example please? I have no idea how to do that. :(

Comment: No, not really, because I don't have a clue what you really want to achieve

Comment: Do you want to document LaTeX code or do you want to [output other comments to LaTeX](https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/formulas.html)?

Comment: I want to write that example in LaTeX, and I thought that it is something special for that. Since is not, i will write that as code. ( [this is for c++](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21106/adding-c-code-in-latex) my question was if there exist somethig like this for doxygen  :D ) sorry if i was unclear.