# How can I have most compact code inside a lstlisting frame?

Tags: lists, line-breaking

I want most compact code inside a `lstlisting` frame. I have tried to fit the frame into the two-column using `xleftmargin=1.1mm,xrightmargin=2.5pt` by manually trying and checking with eye.

But my real problem is I want to change the line breaks for each sentences to fit more words into it.

Please note that I have used `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`, code is taken from answer for [How to change the font style and size for the \lstinputlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/648556/127048) with some changes:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}
{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    frame=single,
    breaklines,
    columns=fullflexible,
    breakindent=1.2em,
    breakatwhitespace,
    escapeinside={(*}{*)},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle,autogobble,xleftmargin=1.1mm,xrightmargin=2.5pt]
    function hello_world(*\,*)(uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint e, uint f) public returns bool {
        uint256 amount = 100
        return true;
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

For example here, I want to have following as the first line:

```tex
function hello_world(uint a, uint b, uint c, uint
```

where shifting `uint` to the first line, hence I believe it will still fit into the frame. I have tried:

```tex
function hello_world(*\,*)(uint a,(*\,*)uint b,(*\,*)uint c,(*\,*)uint
```

but it did not helped.

The first reason I have used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is, but in general I find `nxtt` (the default typewriter font used with NewTX) not particularly attractive and too big:

[image]

Usually typewriter type is a bit smaller then Roman type.

You can do it with some trickery: use the `nott` option and define later the same font family, but scaled at 90%.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nott]{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \providecommand{\ntx@scaled}{}%
  \renewcommand{\ntx@scaled}{s*[0.9]}%
  \renewcommand{\ttdefault}{ntxtt}%
}
\makeatother

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}
{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    frame=single,
    breaklines,
    columns=fullflexible,
    breakindent=1.2em,
    breakatwhitespace,
    escapeinside={(*}{*)},
}
\begin{document}

abc\texttt{abc}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle,autogobble,xleftmargin=1.1mm,xrightmargin=2.5pt]
    function hello_world(*\,*)(uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint e, uint f) public returns bool {
        uint256 amount = 100
        return true;
    }
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum*[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, use an altogether different typewriter font.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nott]{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[scale=0.95]{zi4}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}
{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    frame=single,
    breaklines,
    columns=fullflexible,
    breakindent=1.2em,
    breakatwhitespace,
    escapeinside={(*}{*)},
}
\begin{document}
abc\texttt{abc}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle,autogobble,xleftmargin=1.1mm,xrightmargin=2.5pt]
    function hello_world(*\,*)(uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint e, uint f) public returns bool {
        uint256 amount = 100
        return true;
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\lipsum*[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Last, but not least, you can decide to reduce the fontsize for a particular listing (or all of them) by setting

```
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small
```

or even `\footnotesize`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[nott]{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage[scale=0.95]{zi4}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lstautogobble}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}
{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    frame=single,
    breaklines,
    columns=flexible,
    breakindent=1.2em,
    breakatwhitespace,
    escapeinside={(*}{*)},
}
\lstdefinestyle{mystylesmaller}
{
    style=mystyle,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
}

\begin{document}

abc\texttt{abc}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle,autogobble,xleftmargin=1.1mm,xrightmargin=2.5pt]
    function hello_world(*\,*)(uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint e, uint f) public returns bool {
        uint256 amount = 100
        return true;
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystylesmaller,autogobble,xleftmargin=1.1mm,xrightmargin=2.5pt]
    function hello_world(*\,*)(uint a, uint b, uint c, uint d, uint e, uint f) public returns bool {
        uint256 amount = 100
        return true;
    }
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum*[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which one out of the four examples do you recommend to be used? As I understand second one looks more style, right?  Is there any difference between `lstlisting` and `lstinputlisting `? where can I use `lstinputlisting ` instead ?

Comment: @alper I like more Inconsolata (`zi4`); about the font size, you can take a case by case decision. You can use `\lstinputlisting` when you want to input a file, rather than having the code in the `.tex` file.

Comment: Is it possible to reduce all the row's height size little bit?

Comment: @alper Add `\linespread{0.9}` in front of `\ttfamily`